# Principal directions from a set of vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I have M 3D vectors, all with origin (0,0,0). They all have different directions and lengths.

How can I find the N principal directions? By principal directions I mean the vectors with biggest length, but also different orientations. 
I found that calculating the eigenvectors I can get the 3 first directions, but I can't get more.

Any ideas?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are doing principle component analysis of these M 3D vectors,

since you are doing the Eigen-Decomposition of their Covariance matrix, which is a symmetric matrix, the eigen vectors are orthogonal to each others,

And you can only find at most 3 nonzero distinct vectors that is orthogonal to each other in a 3D space.

Comment: Yes, but I'm not trying to find vectors that are orthogonal to each other, just the N main directions.

Comment: What's your definition for "main directions"? and how exactly you find them?

Comment: I guess my question is if I could get more than 3 eigenvectors (not necessarily orthogonal) for a set of 3D vectors.